# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function in react and redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-router

I am using reactjs and redux for data control,and the code for component is

**Employeeprofile.jsx:**

```
import React from 'react';
import UserPersonalProfile from './UserPersonalProfile.jsx';
import ViewUserPersonal from './ViewUserPersonal.jsx';
import UserBankInformation from './UserBankInformation.jsx';
import UserContactDetails from './UserContactDetails.jsx';
import { Router, Link , Route, Switch ,browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import {personaldetails,employeedetails, personaldetails_response} from '../actions/index.jsx'
import {personaldetailreducer} from '../reducers/personaldetails.jsx'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

class EmployeeProfilePage extends React.Component{

    render()
        {
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="margin">
                            <div className="col-md-12">
                                <div className="main_content">
                                    <div className="row">
                                        <div className="col-md-12">
                                             <div className="row">
                                                 <div className="col-sm-12" data-spy="scroll" data-offset="0">
                                                    <UserPersonalProfile />
                                                 </div>
                                                 <div className="col-sm-6">
                                                    <ViewUserPersonal />
                                                 </div>
                                                 <div className="col-sm-6">
                                                    <UserContactDetails />
                                                 </div>
                                                 <div className="col-sm-6">
                                                    <UserBankInformation />
                                                 </div>
                                             </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default  EmployeeProfilePage;
```

**UserPersonalProfile.jsx:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Link , Route, Switch ,browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import {employeedetails, employeedetails_response} from '../actions/employee_actions.jsx'
import {personaldetailreducer} from '../reducers/personaldetails.jsx'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';


class UserPersonalProfile extends React.Component
{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            EmployeeProfile: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {
            this.props.employeedetails();
            this.setState({EmployeeProfile:this.props.employeedetails()})
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="panel panel-info">
                <div className="panel-heading">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div  className="col-lg-12 panel-title">
                            <strong>Your Personal Profile</strong><span className="pull-right"><Link to='/home' className="view-all-front btn btn-default">Go Back</Link></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-lg-12 well-user-profile">
                    <div className="row">                            
                        <div className="col-lg-2 col-sm-3">
                            <div className="fileinput-new">
                                <img src="/static/users/app/images/profilepic.jpg" id="accountimg" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-lg-8 col-sm-8 ">
                            <div className="personalprofile">                                        
                                <h3></h3>
                                <hr />
                                <dl className="dl-horizontal">
                                    <dt id="detail1">Employee Code</dt>

                                    <dt id="detail2">Biometric ID</dt>

                                    <dt id="detail3">Department</dt>

                                    <dt id="detail4">Designation</dt>

                                    <dt id="detail5">Joining Date</dt>
                                </dl>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state,props) {
    console.log(state,'state data')
    console.log(props,'props data')

  return {
    EmployeeProfile: state
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    employeedetails: UserPersonalProfile
  }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserPersonalProfile);
```

Reducers:

personaldetails.jsx:

```
import { FETCH_USER_DATA ,
         FETCH_USER_SUCCESS,
         FETCH_USER_ERROR
       } from '../actions/constants'


const initialState =
    {
        "first_name": " ",
        "last_name": " ",
        "email": "",
        "profile": null,
        "fetching":false,
        "fetched" :false,
        "error":null
    }



// Takes care of changing the application state
function personaldetailreducer (state=initialState, action)

        {
            switch (action.type)
            {

                case "FETCH_USER_DATA":
                    return Object.assign({}, state, action.payload);

                case "FETCH_USER_DATA_ERROR":
                    return {state,fetching:false,error:action.payload};

            }

            return state
        }

export default personaldetailreducer
```

Actions:

**employee_actions.jsx:**

```
import {
    LOGIN_FORM,
    LOGIN_API,
    USER_PERSONAL_DETAILS_API,
    EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_API,
    FETCH_USER_DATA,
    FETCH_EMPLOYEE_DATA,
    FETCH_EMPLOYEE_DATA_SUCCESS,
    FETCH_EMPLOYEE_DATA_ERROR,
    FETCH_USER_SUCCESS,
    FETCH_USER_ERROR

} from './constants';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link ,browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise';
import configureStore from '../store/store.jsx'

/* Using EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_API,user is authenticated using token and corresponsing user profile details is
 displayed in front end */

    export  function employeedetails() {
        var hash_token ='Token '+ localStorage.getItem('usertoken');

        return dispatch => {
            axios.get(EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_API,
                    {headers:{'Authorization': hash_token,
                         'Content-Type' : "application/json"
                    }})
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res,'responseeeeeeeeeeeeee')
                    var profile_response = res;
                    dispatch(employeedetails_response(profile_response));
                            });

                        };
                    }

/* Using EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_API ,user is authenticated using token and corresponsing user profile details is
 displayed in front end */

    export const employeedetails_response = (response) =>
    ({
            type:FETCH_EMPLOYEE_DATA ,
            payload: response
    })
```

Here,the issue is when i am calling component onload, i am getting "Cannot call class a function".As I am calling the above component inside another component the issue came.

The component '**UserPersonalProfile.jsx**' is used inside '**EmployeeProfilePage.jsx**' and its reducers and actions is used.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @priya, welcome to SO. Could you also paste the code where you are using this component?

Comment: I'm not a pro with redux but I think the problem is here:

      `return bindActionCreators({
        employeedetails: UserPersonalProfile
      }, dispatch);`
signature is `bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)` Yes you are passing an object but the value is a component?

Comment: @jonathandion , I have to edit the code as 'bindActionCreators(employeedetails,dispatch) ah?

Comment: Yes pass action object `employeedetails`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is pretty easy,

In your `mapDispatchToProps` function, you are calling `bindActionCreators` wrongly, you need not bind it to the component but the action as

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    employeedetails: employeedetails
  }, dispatch);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here:

```
  return bindActionCreators({
    employeedetails: UserPersonalProfile
  }, dispatch);
```

[bindActionCreators](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html) signature is `bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)`

> actionCreators (Function or Object): An action creator, or an object
>   whose values are action creators.

Change the value of `employeedetails` for your action creator `employeedetails`(employee_actions.jsx) instead of your `Component`.

```
  return bindActionCreators({
    employeedetails: employeedetails
  }, dispatch);
```

Comment: I'm glad I helped! Can you accept the answer? Thank you.

Comment: yeah sure.I accepted the answer.but i can't give upvote as i have less points